# jquery.tmpl templates break XHTML-validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

I've document with the following doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="ru">
```

Templates are declared as following:

```
 <script id="tmpl-periods-options" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">   
        {{each plans_array}} 
            <label><input type="radio" value="${$value.id}" name="pf-periods" {{if $value.selected}}checked="checked" {{/if}} />${$value.title}</label>
        {{/each}}           
    </script>
```

http://validator.w3.org/ shows me errors about html code which is declared inside `<script>` tag.

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normal JavaScript techniques don't work as this isn't JavaScript; simply wrapping the template in `//<![CDATA[ ... //]]>` or `//<!-- ... //-->` just causes worse problems.

As suggested in [this blog post](http://lchandara.wordpress.com/2011/01/02/jquery-templates-xhtml-validation/), it seems like the best options are either use HTML 5 or place the template in an external file and include that.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get('template.html', function(content) {
        $.template('template name', content);
    });
});
```

Comment: Yep, I've tried CDATA in first place, no luck -- final `]]>` became a part of a template (it can be sripped though).